# GetPixel method is not found

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing

I have a simple program, and ive included System.Drawing and I do not have an ability to use the GetPixel() method. It says its not found. What could be the reason for this?

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace isolatepixels
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            System.Drawing.Image image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\1.jpg");

            int x, y;

            // Loop through the images pixels to reset color. 
            for (x = 0; x < image1.Width; x++)
            {
                for (y = 0; y < image1.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x, y);
                    Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R, 0, 0);
                    image1.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
                }
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `using System.Drawing` at the top of the source code file? And how did you get hold of the `Graphics` object?

Comment: ive added the code for you

Comment: The built in `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` methods are very slow. If you need to improve performance you can look into other methods such as LockBits. [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp)

Comment: Don't use Image.FromFile(), use the Bitmap(string) constructor instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT] As Hans says in his comment above, you can skip the `Image.FromFile()` and pass the filename directly to the `Bitmap` constructor if you are not using the image itself anywhere.

An `Image` object doesn't contain those methods and nor does a `Graphics` object, but a `Bitmap` object does. So the trick is to create a `Bitmap` from the image, using [`new Bitmap(image)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts25csc8.aspx) like so:

```
// Don't need this: Image image1 = Image.FromFile(@"C:\1.jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\1.jpg");

// Save the image in JPEG format.
bitmap.Save(@"C:\test.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

int x, y;

// Loop through the images pixels to reset color. 

for (x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
    {
        Color pixelColor = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
        Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R, 0, 0);
        bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
    }
}
```

Note that `Bitmap` derives from `System.Drawing.Image`.

I *think* that should work.

Comment: i need to find the color of the pixel, thank you for the help