# bitmap setpixel c# marshalbyrefobject weird exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I import the library System.Drawing (i put the reference to System.Drawin to the project) to work with bitmaps but when i use the SetPixel method it send the next exception:

Reference to type 'MarshalByRefObject' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found.

How can i fixed it ?

(I dont put code because is basically bm.setpixel(a,b,c))

References:

https://i.gyazo.com/c197edbe8b5e4d224af0485eb1be0ea2.png

I am using .NET 4.5 and visual studio 2015

Comment: Similar issue here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1023560/Reference-to-type-MarshalByRefObject-claims-it-is

Comment: i added the reference to System.Drawing, that thread didnt help me.

Comment: What about his reference problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390148/getpixel-method-is-not-found. And it's easier to help if you post the code.

Comment: Please read the notes on positing a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. We don't want to have to guess how you're creating your bitmap.

Comment: to create the bitmap i am using Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(width,heigth);

Comment: It works fine for me doing: `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100); bmp.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.Red);` however I'm using .net4.

Comment: You cannot use System.Drawing in projects that target .NETCore.  You'll have to pick a class that's appropriate for the target, like BitmapSource.

Comment: it works thanks Hans